# How can I convert a class name into the equivalent in JNI in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Given an object `obj` from a Java class called `MyExample` (in package `a.b.c`) and then doing the following:

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
```

It will print the string:

```
a.b.c.MyExample
```

Now, I would like to convert this into the equivalent in JNI:

```
La/b/c/MyExample;
```

What is the method that I should call to get to this result?

Comment: If you have a reason for tagging C for this questin please explain and add the tag again. For now I will remove it.

Comment: String.replace(".", "/");

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: is it safe to do this operation? I mean, I pretend to consume the result in JNI and if there are some hidden rules that I'm not aware of, it will return an error. The example that I posted above (`La.b.c.MyExample;`) is what JNI needs in order to consume class `a.b.c.MyExample` but I'm not sure if there are corner-cases.  To summarize: can you do a simple replace like you suggest and then passed on JNI assuming all use-cases are covered?

Comment: I fail to see any practical use in this; b/c one can determine the calling class in JNI.

Comment: Edge cases were simple replacing **could** not work could be primitives and nested classes (including lambdas).

Comment: @MartinZeitler: could you provide an example on how this is done in JNI? Thanks!

Comment: @user7698505 You've not provided any meaningful reason for what you'd need that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you won't have a simple, straight forward way of doing so :( At least I am not aware of one.

You can follow instruction on how native signatures are created and follow the path (the other way round):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#resolving_native_method_names

You can also take a look at how `javap` tool does that (note that `javap` can provide you with signatures).

For class:

```
package a.b.c;

public class Simple {
  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    Simple s = new Simple();
    System.out.println(s.getClass().toString());
  }

  public void callOnMe(Simple s) {

  }
}
```

you will get

```
> javap -s -cp . a.b.c.Simple
Compiled from "Simple.java"
public class a.b.c.Simple {
  public a.b.c.Simple();
    descriptor: ()V

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V

  public void callOnMe(a.b.c.Simple);
    descriptor: (La/b/c/Simple;)V
}
```

However, if you take a closer look at `javap` itself:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk

and then inside

```
./jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javap/ClassWriter.java
```

you will note that there is no magic there, just bare bone parsing.

**Note**

In case somebody has a solution in a form `SomeClass.getMangledName()` I'd love to learn it as well :)